# Is there a way to have a text view android:autoLink="" go to a SMS app instead?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, autolink

I am Trying to keep the number highlighting  but shoot the number to a SMS app I can do an on click thing and manually send it there but then I lose the blue lettering. Is there a simple way to do this?